# Akka Scheduler: Wait for Runnable to complete

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

So I have the following Akka scheduler setup

```
implicit val testActorSystem = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "test-actor-system")
implicit val executionContext = testActorSystem.executionContext

val cleaner: Runnable = () => //do something

val cancellable: Cancellable = testActorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0 seconds, cleaner)
```

I want to wait until my `Runnable` is done. How can I check this? I understand that this task is transformed into `Future`s under the hood but in this case I cannot access these `Future`s and wait on them. What is the best practice to wait for the task to complete then?

Comment: is for a test or for production code?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, does it matter?

Comment: Note that "this task is transformed into `Future`s under the hood" is incorrect: no such transformation needs to occur (see, e.g. `LightArrayRevolverScheduler`, which executes the `Runnable` by passing it through a `TaskHolder` for execution in an `ExecutionContext`).

Comment: In the specific case of your code, if you want a task to execute in the very near future (in `0 seconds`) and get a `Future` that completes when the task is done, why not `Future { cleaner.run() }`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have control of the `Runnable`, you could have the `Runnable` complete a `Promise`'s `Future`:

```
import akka.Done
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

val (cleaner, cleanerDoneFut) = {
  val donePromise = Promise[Done]

  val cleaner: Runnable = () => {
    try {
      // do stuff
      donePromise.success(Done)
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => donePromise.failure(e)
    }
  }

  cleaner -> donePromise.future
}

val cancellable = ...
```

Obviously, this can only be done with a `Runnable` that you expect to execute exactly once.

Note that you can wrap any `Runnable` into a `Runnable` which completes a `Future` when it's finished with:

```
// the future will contain the result of the first time the returned runnable runs
def runnableWithCompletionFuture(runnable: Runnable): (Runnable, Future[Done]) = {
  val donePromise = Promise[Done]

  val wrapped = try {
    runnable.run()
    donePromise.success(Done)
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => donePromise.failure(e)
  }

  wrapped -> donePromise.future
}

def scheduleWithCompletion(when: FiniteDuration)(r: Runnable)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem): (Cancellable, Future[Done]) = {
  val (wrapped, fut) = runnableWithCompletionFuture(r)
  val c = actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(when, wrapped)
  c -> fut
}
```

From digging through the implementation, absent a trick like this, there's no way to tell whether an arbitrary scheduled `Runnable` has completed.

Comment: Unfortunately this changes the `Runnable`'s implementation so I cannot really use it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that. You call the [method](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Scheduler.scala#L486):

```
def scheduleOnce(delay: FiniteDuration, runnable: Runnable)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Cancellable
```

While [`Cancellable`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Scheduler.scala#L518) is:

```
trait Cancellable {

  /**
   * Cancels this Cancellable and returns true if that was successful.
   * If this cancellable was (concurrently) cancelled already, then this method
   * will return false although isCancelled will return true.
   *
   * Java & Scala API
   */
  def cancel(): Boolean

  /**
   * Returns true if and only if this Cancellable has been successfully cancelled
   *
   * Java & Scala API
   */
  def isCancelled: Boolean
}
```

So I don't think there is such option.

Comment: I'm trying to relate this to Java's `ExecutorService`. With this service you can still schedule tasks and wait for their termination - `awaitTermination`. So do you know what is the rationale behind a scheduler which does not provide such a functionality? What does the scheduler do when the main thread exits? Will it wait for the spawned threads to finish?

Comment: @Niko, The jvm waits for all running threads to complete. If you want, you can add a shutdown hook, and cancel the running job.

Comment: The intended use of Akka's scheduler is for deferring tasks which are very short (think sub-millisecond), with the canonical intended task being to send one or more messages to one or more actors.  (In fact, Viktor Klang has been quoted as saying that it should have been called a Deferer, not a Scheduler).  It's not really intended for execution of general tasks.

Comment: @LeviRamsey could you please point me to some official Akka docs that mention this "shortness" of tasks. For sure, by reading [the these docs  here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scheduler.html#) it is more than clear that the scheduler is **not intended for long-term tasks**.